# MSBuild isn't resolving the correct path from an imported file

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm having an issue with MSBuild 4.0 not resolving a path correctly in one of my imported MSBuild files. *ProjectOne.csproj* at the very beginning of the file imports *GenericProject.proj*.

*GenericProject.proj* then goes on to import the *ProjectOne.settings* file when it needs it via a call structured like:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectName).settings" />
```

I had assumed that when the import was resolved it would have a path of something like:

*/Project Root/Src/ProjectOne/ProjectOne.settings*

But when running  the *ProjectOne.csproj* through MSBuild I got a path of:

*/Project Root/Targets/ProjectOne.settings*

This doesn't make sense because considering all paths are suppose to be relative of the master project, in this case *ProjectOne.csproj*.

So I'm wondering if someone knows why this is happening?

**Folder Structure:**

- Project Root

  - Src

    - ProjectOne

      - ProjectOne.csproj
      - ProjectOne.settings
  - Targets

    - GenericProject.proj

I don't think this matters, but just in case I'm running windows 7 x64

**Edit:** *(1:45-11/7/2010)* I was able to solve the problem by adding the `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` tag in front of `$(MSBuildProjectName)` but I still don't know why it wasn't resolving correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all paths are suppose [sic] to be relative of the master project

Where did you get that idea?

`<Import>` elements are relative to the importing file.